# Passing Strings with !,' '... symbols into jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, youtube-data-api, google-api-js-client

I'm working with Goolge Apis using javascript and jquery

The problem is some YouTube Channel's Titles have 'SPACE' OR ! OR ... symbols

So I need to pass those Titles as Strings but even then I get error

`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #channelBomB!`

My code is below

```
function placeChannelVideoIds(YouTubeChannelTitle){

    $('#channel'+String(YouTubeChannelTitle)).append('\
        <H1>YouTubeChannelTitle</H1>>);

}
placeChannelVideoIds(String(YouTubeChannelTitle));
```

Comment: The error you quote isn't about whether it is a string, it is because the result of your concatenation is a string that is not a valid CSS / jQuery element selector. What creates the elements you're trying to select with `$('#channel' +...)`, and what sets those elements' IDs?

Comment: @nnnnnn the problem is not concatenation It's due to having symbols in the string and also spaces.So,now I'm using Channel Id which are in (A-Z,a-z,0-9,-,_)

Comment: I didn't say concatenation was the problem, I said it was invalid selectors.

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah you are right sorry for wrong sentence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not about the string you try to append, it is the id can't have any whitespace, tag or `!`, basically, you can only use `a-zA-Z`, `0-9`, `_-.`

> #### `id` in HTML 4
>
> For HTML 4, ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
>
> #### `id` in HTML 5
>
> HTML 5 accept '_', '-' and '.' if not at the beginning fo the id. It is also a true global attribute.
>
> **id attribute's value must not contain whitespace (spaces, tabs etc.)**. Browsers treat non-conforming IDs that contain whitespace as if the whitespace is part of the ID. In contrast to the class attribute, which allows space-separated values, elements can only have one single ID.
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

---

## Solution:

Ok, so you can't use any string in id, **but you can hash the string to get a unique number and used as an id, and you hash the same string you always get the same unique id**.

Then your code will look like this (add the `sdbmCode` function to your code):

```
function placeChannelVideoIds(YouTubeChannelTitle){
    var hash_id = sdbmCode(YouTubeChannelTitle);
    $('#channel'+ hash_id).append('<h1>'+YouTubeChannelTitle+'</h1>');
}
placeChannelVideoIds(YouTubeChannelTitle);
```

As you can see in the below code example, any string can be hashed into a unique id (well, it is very very very rare you will get the same id from two different string(like winning lottery 3 times in a row)).

> REF: http://erlycoder.com/49/javascript-hash-functions-to-convert-string-into-integer-hash-

```js
sdbmCode = function(str){
    var hash = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        char = str.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = char + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash;
    }
    return Math.abs(hash);
}

var str1 = 'BomB!';
var str2 = 'Bo mB!';
var str3 = '!!$%#^^@';
var str4 = 'test!!$%#^^@';
var str5 = 'test!!$%#^^@!';
var str6 = '"test!!$%#^^@"';

console.log('hash '+str1+'    -->'+sdbmCode(str1));
console.log('hash '+str1+'    -->'+sdbmCode(str1));
console.log('hash '+str2+'   -->'+sdbmCode(str2));
console.log('hash '+str3+'        -->'+sdbmCode(str3));
console.log('hash '+str4+'    -->'+sdbmCode(str4));
console.log('hash '+str5+'    -->'+sdbmCode(str5));
console.log('hash '+str6+'   -->'+sdbmCode(str6));
```

Comment: Thank you @Daniel for solution but now I'm not using Channel Titles so there are no errors